# Double or nested "such that" notation

Tags: notation

I have searched the questions regarding notation of "such that" in this forum but only encountered discussions on the use of : vs. | and less common alternatives.

In some cases I find myself in need of using two "such that" formulations in a nested fashion in set builder notation, consider the following example:

We consider some set of points $\textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and some vector of functions $\textbf{r} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now let the subset $\mathcal{F} = \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} : \textbf{r}(\textbf{x}) \leq \textbf{0} \}$ be called the set of feasible points (where the inequality is understood to hold pointwise), then its complement could be denoted as $\{ \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} : \exists i : r_i(\textbf{x}) > 0 \}$.

While I suppose this notation is valid, it is not very intuitive as it relies on right associativity of the existential quantifier which (at least IMHO) is not very satisfying.

Instead I would actually consider a mixture of notations such as $$\{ \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} : \exists i | r_i(\textbf{x}) > 0 \}$$ easier to understand.

- Is there a downside to this mixed notation that I am unaware of?
- Is there some common practice for nested such that notation?

Comment: I don't think this is very common, but when it is used you usally write $\{ x \in X | (\exists i) r_i(x)>0\}$ or also $\{ x \in X | (\exists i)[ r_i(x)>0]\}$. Also nothing prevents you from writing $\{x \in X | \exists i \: s.t. \: r_i(x)>0 \}$. If you use $:$ and $|$ I would intuitively do it the other way around: $\{x \in X | \exists i : r_i(x)>0\}$.

Comment: The syntax is $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$, that reads: "the set of all and only those $x$ such that $\varphi$ holds", where $\varphi(x)$ is a formula with $x$ free, i.e. expressing a "condition" on $x$.

Comment: Thsu, we may have: $\{ \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} : \exists i \ (r_i(\textbf{x}) > 0) \}$ which abbreviates: $\{ \textbf{x} :  \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} \land \exists i \ (r_i(\textbf{x}) > 0) \}$. The expression $ \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X} \land \exists i \ (r_i(\textbf{x}) > 0)$ is our $\varphi(  \textbf{x} )$.